# find the parallel from the center of the inscribed circle of an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

[image]

$ABC$ - isosceles triangle. $O$ - the center of the inscribed circle of the triangle.

$EF$ || $BC$

Given $AB = 24 cm$ and $AF=18cm$, find out $EF =?$

If it's possible, I would be interested in a demonstration without using Fundamental theorem of similarity or the bisector theorem.

Comment: What did you get for EF using similar triangles approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AOF$ and $AHC$ are similar triangles.

$AO=3r$ and $OF=\sqrt{18^2-9r^2}$.

$AOF$ is a right triangle and
$$OK=\frac{AO\cdot OF}{AF}$$
So we get the equation
$$3r\sqrt{18^2-9r^2}=18r$$
simplify
$$\sqrt{324-9r^2}=6$$
square both sides
$$324-9r^2=36\to r=4\sqrt{2}$$
So $OF=6$ and $EF=12$.

[image]

Comment: Grazie, @Raffaele